# MarkupBuilder - Generate attributes without encapsulation

Tags: groovy, markupbuilder

Is it possible to generate attributes using MarkupBuilder() without encapsulating it. I have the following:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

// generate strings with double quotes
xml.setDoubleQuotes(true);


invoiceId = "123456XXX";
date = "2023-01-06";
amount = 220.36;
  
xml.consolidate(amount:amount.toDouble(),
                    date: date,
                    invoiceId: invoiceId,
                    currency:'EUR');
  
}
```

but it generates:

```
<consolidate amount="220.36" date="2023-01-06" invoiceId="123456XXX" currency="EUR" />
</consolidate>
```

when the following is expected:

```
 <consolidate amount=220.36 date="2023-01-06" invoiceId="123456XXX" currency="EUR" />
</consolidate>
```

Comment: I thought all XML attributes were always strings

Answer (score 1):

The result that you put as "expected" is not a valid XML (you may check it with the [validator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)). The attribute's value is always quoted:

> Attribute values must always be quoted. Either single or double quotes
> can be used.

See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp).

For that reason you shouldn't and probably can't make `MarkupBuilder` to produce the desired result.

Comment: To be fair, the "_desired result_" is wrong, and whatever desires it should be changed